# I need to press a button twice to execute onClickListener - Android

Tags: android, button, listener

I can't figure out why i need to tap twice on a "submit" button. I have a simple form with 2 TextInputLayouts and a button that calls some logic to be executed, but it gets executed only when i press that button to times.

Follows the code:

XML

```xml
<Button
  android:id="@+id/accedibtn"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/pwDimenticataTextViewAccedi"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
  android:text="@string/access"
  android:textColor="@color/black"
  android:textSize="14sp"
  tools:ignore="TextSizeCheck" />
```

Listener in onCreate method

```
accedi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkUser(view);
                if (account != null){
                    Routing.dashboardActivity(Login.this, account);
                }
            }
        });
```

CheckUser Function

```
private void checkUser(View v){
        String emailString = String.valueOf(email.getText());
        String passwordString = String.valueOf(password.getText());
        
        db.getCOLLECTION_ACCOUNT().whereEqualTo(DatabaseConstants.KEY_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, emailString)
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                List<DocumentSnapshot> document = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                if(document.size()==1) {
                    String pwCheck = (String) document.get(0).get(DatabaseConstants.KEY_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);
                    if (passwordString.equals(pwCheck))
                        account = document.get(0).toObject(Account.class);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, Testi.toastError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            });
    }
```

Probably the checkUser function needs to be in another class, I don't know. in any case, I expect that when i tap on button this code will be executed, but it doesn't.

Probably is a simple question, but I have been programming on android for only 2 months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what kind of a database you are using (maybe Firestore, not important), but `.get()` seems to be an *asynchronous operation* as you have the `OnSuccessListener` and `OnFailureListener` to handle the outcome.

So, the flow in your app is now:

- Button is clicked
- The operation to read the user account data from the DB is started
- The DB operation is being processed...
- Meanwhile your code proceeds to `if (account != null){...}`
- The `account` is still null at that point
- The DB operation is completed at some point and `account` is no longer null
- The next time the button is clicked `account != null is true`

Maybe the `OnSuccessListener` should do the `Routing.dashboardActivity()`?

Anyway, you'll need to slightly re-think your application logic.

Comment: That’s true…so what I need to do is using threads or something that is blocking? Am I right? 
Because “account” can be seen like a critic section

Comment: Without knowing more about your app, I'd say that the `OnSuccessListener` should do the `Routing.dashboardActivity()` call or trigger some other method that calls it.